# If $f$ is Riemann int. on $[0,b)$ for all $b>0$ and Lebesgue int. on $[0,\infty)$ then $\int_{[0,\infty)}f\,dm = \lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^bf(x)\,dx$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I'm trying to understand a relation between a certain improper Riemann integral and the corresponding Lebesgue integral.

In particular, Folland claims that if $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,b)$ for all $b>0$ and Lebesgue integrable on $[0,\infty)$ then $\int_{[0,\infty)}f\,dm = \lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^bf(x)\,dx$. He claims this is a consequence of the dominated convergence theorem. I fail to see why. Using the dominated convergence theorem I have shown that indeed $\int_{[0,\infty)}f\,dm = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^nf(x)\,dx$. I do not see why $\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^bf(x)\,dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^nf(x)\,dx$.

The dominated convergence theorem makes an assertion about limits of *sequences* of integrals whereas what we have on the left hand side of the last equation is the limit of integrals defined for each *real* non-negative $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_{[0,\infty)} fdm=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{b_n} fdm=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{b_n} f(x)dx$ for **any sequence** $b_n$ tending to $\infty$. This implies that   $\int_{[0,\infty)} fdm=\lim_{b \to \infty} \int_0^{b}f(x)dx$.

Comment: Okay, I will try to show this. Is this a typical technique used to show equivalence of improper Riemann integrals and Lebesgue integrals? It seems similar to the fact that a real valued sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ if and only if each subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $x$.

Comment: @SimonSMN In general, $F(x) \to L$ as $x \to \infty$ iff $F(x_n) \to L$ for every sequenec $(x_n)$ tending to $\infty$.

Comment: I definitely knew about the only if direction. I will try to prove the if direction now.

Comment: Perhaps you could do the if direction?

Comment: @SimonSMN Use proof by contradiction. Can you write down what it means to say that $F(x)$ does not tend to $L$ as $x$ tends to $\infty$?

Comment: Okay, that does it I think. If I suppose $F(x) \to L$ as $x\to\infty$ is false, then there is an $\epsilon$ such that for each $B \geq 0$ there exists $x_0\geq B$ with $|F(x_0)-L| > \epsilon$. Hence I can pick a sequence $(x_n)$ tending to $\infty$ such that $|F(x_n)-L| > \epsilon$ for all $n$. Then in particular $F(x_n) \to L$ as $n \to \infty$ is false. Thus the right hand side of the equivalence is false. This shows the contrapositive. Hence your statement follows. Correct?